# Android parse nested tables with Jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to parse an HTML page online to retrieve data from a table with Jsoup. The page I want to parse contains more than one table.

How can I do that?

Here is a sample page that I want to parse:

https://www.cpu-world.com/info/AMD/AMD_A4-Series.html

The data I want to extract is the Model Name and the URL of the details page.

Edit:

This is some of the code I'm using to extract data from the details page.

```
            try {
                /**
                 * Works to iterate through the items at the following website
                 * https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-A4-Series%20A4-3300.html
                 */
                URL url = new URL("https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-A4-Series%20A4-3300.html");
                
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
                
                // spec_table is the name of the class associated with the table
                Elements table = doc.select("table.spec_table");
                Elements rows = table.select("tr");
                
                Iterator<Element> rowIterator = rows.iterator();
                rowIterator.next();
                boolean wasMatch = false;
                
                // Loop through all items in list
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Element row = rowIterator.next();
                    Elements cols = row.select("td");
                    String rowName = cols.get(0).text();
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I've been reading some tutorials as well as the documentation and I can't seem to figure out how to navigate the web pages to extract the data I'm looking for. I understand the HTML and CSS, but am just learning about Jsoup.

(I tagged this as Android because that's where I'm using the Java code. Guess it's not necessary to be that specific.)

Comment: yes it's possible. show us what you have tried so far, add some code. there have lots of tutorial available online. btw why did you tag android with this question?

Comment: Have you simply clicked the **`View Source`** Button in your Chrome or Edge Browser?  This page is an **AJAX Page** and, particularly, that table is loaded by **JavaScript** so **JSoup** is not going to get that data you have requested.  You wanted the `URL` and Model Number of each product in the table?  Is that what your question is asking?  I can work on a solution, but it will not use the **JSoup** library.

Comment: I pressed F12 in Chrome to look at the code there. It never occurred to me it was something like that (AJAX), only that I can get data from numerous other sites without issue.
How can you tell it's AJAX so I know what to look for next time?
Yes, the URL and Model Number is what I was looking for.

Comment: Well... **Question 1** How can you tell if **Java-Script**, **AJAX**, (or **Angular JS, Type Script, React JS**) - print out the HTML that is downloaded when you poll the web-server...  The `View Source` Button sometimes helps, but sometimes will confuse you because the **HTML** that it shows you isn't always exactly what was downloaded by the first poll of the server.  **Question 2** Is there a way to get the information from a `script loaded` page?  Yeah, sort of...  There are script executing packages, but I just got sick and I need to lay down, so I cannot write it this second... :)

Comment: Sorry for the "free comments" (with no answer) ...  I need to sleep, first.

Comment: It's OK if you don't have time or energy now. At least now I know why I was having so much trouble with it and I'm not the only one.

Comment: OK... (I had walnuts for breakfast - MISTAKE!... I wonder what they will say about my comments today on SO)...  ***SO, AS IT TURNS OUT*** - What I am getting from this particular web-site is some serious "Scrape Detection" and "Bot Detection" stuff.  It is usually pretty rare to encounter "Bot Detection" (most web-sites have no problems with people downloading there information, usually they like it)...  I tried with a proxy for executing script, and without one... Both versions I have tried give me ***Access Denied*** and `HTTP-403: [Forbidden], Category: Client errors`

Comment: This IP address is blocked.</b><p>We deny access to:</p><ul><li>Open proxies</li><li>Addresses within data center IP ranges</li><li>Automated requests and most types of bots</li><li>Visitors that post spam in comments and/or forums, attempt to circumvent site security, or scrap the content of our site.</li></ul>

Comment: I am not saying it is impossible to scrape this site, all I am saying is I personally don't know how...  As I said, ***Bot Detection*** usually only happens (for me, anyway, but I stay away from a lot of sites) ... ***once in a blue moon...***

Comment: You said there are two tables - which two do you want? I'm not seeing any issues with AJAX? If I take what you have and list `doc.select("table")` I see 7 tables extracted by JSoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like what you're after:

```java
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class CpuWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            /**
             * Works to iterate through the items at the following website
             * https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-A4-Series%20A4-3300.html
             */
             url = new URL("https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-A4-Series%20A4-3300.html");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
        // spec_table is the name of the class associated with the table
        String modelNumber = doc.select("table tr:has(td:contains(Model number)) td b a").text();
        String modelUrl = doc.select("table tr:has(td:contains(Model number)) td b a").attr("href");

        System.out.println(modelNumber + " : " + modelUrl);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is not what you're after

EDIT: Results:

```sh
A4-3300 : https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-A4-Series%20A4-3300.html

Process finished with exit code 0
```

EDIT:

This is crazier than a box of frogs but here we go... I'll leave you to put 2 and 2 together to iterate through the URLs to get the individual details you're after:

```java
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CpuWorld {

    public static final String CPU_WORLD_COM_URL = "https://www.cpu-world.com/info/AMD/AMD_A4-Series.html";

    public static final String SCRAMBLED_DATA_HEADER = "<!--\r\nfunction JSC_Process () {var bk,xg,qh,k,aj,y,e,cq,u,a,ei;\r\na=\"";
    public static final String SCRAMBLED_DATA_FOOTER = "//- qh=[\"\"];k=[2];cq=[7600];if (CW_AB){if\t((AB_v!='0')&&(AB_v!='X')&&(AB_Gl((AB_v=='')?99:3)==3)){y=1;AB_cb=function(){JSC_Process();};}else{y=2;}}for(aj=e=0;aj<k.length;aj++){ei=cq[aj];bk=qh[aj];if (!bk) bk=\"JSc_\"+aj;u=CW_E(bk);if (u){bk=\" jsc_a\";if (y>=k[aj]){xg=a.substr(e,ei);xg=xg.replace(/(.)(.)/g,\"$2$1\");u.innerHTML=xg.replace(/\\\\n/g,\"\\n\");bk='';}u.className=u.className.replace(/(^| )jsc_\\w+$/,bk);}e+=ei;}}JSC_Process();";

    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document tableData = getTableData(CPU_WORLD_COM_URL);

        List<String> fullUrls = tableData.select("table tr td:contains(a) a").stream()
                .map(e -> "https://www.cpu-world.com/" + e.attr("href"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<String> fullModels = tableData.select("table tr td:contains(a) a").stream()
                .map(e -> e.text())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (int i=0; i< fullUrls.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(fullModels.get(i) + " : " + fullUrls.get(i));
        }
    }

    private static Document getTableData(String url) {
        Connection.Response response = null;
        try {
            response = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .headers(getHeaders())
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .data()
                    .execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Elements script = Jsoup.parse(response.body()).select("script");

        // take substring of the child node from after the header and before the footer (- 6 more chars which seem dynamic)
        // The script tag containing JSC_Process is the one with the data in (but all mangled).
        Optional<String> scrambledData = script.stream()
                .filter(element -> element.data().contains("JSC_Process"))
                .map(node -> node.data().substring(SCRAMBLED_DATA_HEADER.length(), (node.data().length() - SCRAMBLED_DATA_FOOTER.length()-6)))
                .findFirst();

        String tableData = Unscrambler.unscramble(scrambledData.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("scrambled data not found in relevant script tag")));

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(tableData);
        return doc;
    }

    private static boolean isNotEmptyString(Element node) {
        return node.data() != null && !node.data().equals("");
    }

    /**
    * trick server into thinking we're not a bot
    * by telling the server we were referred by the server itself
    * and give tell it we're using a Mozilla/Safari browser
    **/
    private static Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
        Map<String, String> headersMap = new HashMap<>();
        headersMap.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 Safari/537.36");
        headersMap.put("Referer", CPU_WORLD_COM_URL);
        return headersMap;
    }
}

class Unscrambler {

    public static final String SCRAMBLED_DATA_HEADER = "<!--\r\nfunction JSC_Process () {var bk,xg,qh,k,aj,y,e,cq,u,a,ei;\r\na=\"";
    public static final String SCRAMBLED_DATA_FOOTER = "qh=[\"\"];k=[2];cq=[7600];if (CW_AB){if\t((AB_v!='0')&&(AB_v!='X')&&(AB_Gl((AB_v=='')?99:3)==3)){y=1;AB_cb=function(){JSC_Process();};}else{y=2;}}for(aj=e=0;aj<k.length;aj++){ei=cq[aj];bk=qh[aj];if (!bk) bk=\"JSc_\"+aj;u=CW_E(bk);if (u){bk=\" jsc_a\";if (y>=k[aj]){xg=a.substr(e,ei);xg=xg.replace(/(.)(.)/g,\"$2$1\");u.innerHTML=xg.replace(/\\\\n/g,\"\\n\");bk='';}u.className=u.className.replace(/(^| )jsc_\\w+$/,bk);}e+=ei;}}JSC_Process();";

    public static String unscramble(String data) {
        String a=data.replace("\\\"","'")
                .replace("\\\\", "\\")
                .replace("\\r", "")
                .replace("\\n", "")
                .replace("\"+\r\n\"", ""); // remove gunk that mucks up processing in java
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int e = 0;
        int ei = 2;

        // This is effectively what the code in the footer is doing. Heavily un-obfuscated below.
        // swap two chars around - through
        for (int aj=0; aj < a.length()-2; aj+=2) {
            String xg = a.substring(e, ei);
            buffer.append(xg.substring(1,2) + xg.substring(0,1));
            e+=2;
            ei+=2;
        }
        return buffer.toString().replace("\n","");
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the code you have pasted directly...  I got:  `HTTP-403: [Forbidden], Category: Client errors`

Comment: I use ***Google Cloud Platform*** for running Java - so unless ***CPU World*** has banned **GCP**, I still don't get it... (I don't use **JSoup**, but I have the **JAR** and ran this `class`, and received an `HTTP 403`)

Comment: Interesting but why are you running in GCP? I suspect there may be an IP Range filter so perhaps a proxied url would work? Could be worth debugging the URL via curl first using `-vv` option?

Comment: Hmm...  (This is for my own edification, I'm not the OP)... So.. You say that you compiled ***that code*** posted in the answer above, and retrieved `modelNumber` and `modelURL` just fine?  I mean, when my stuff breaks I like to find out why...  ***YES*** I use **GCP** for all of my development, I'm just used to their **IDE** at this point - and their servers have ultra-fast processors (faster than my desktop)...  I compiled your class, and the **CPU World Server** sent me a `403 Forbidden`...  I will try to put my thinking cap on... Thanks!

Comment: works perfectly ... I've updated the result above to show output

Comment: The code provided does work as expected. However, it's based on a URL I was using in my example that already worked for the Details Page of a single item. It's the list of items at the following URL I'm looking for.

https://www.cpu-world.com/info/AMD/AMD_A4-Series.html

Comment: hmmm.. I can see the data and no its not AJAX/React or anything like that - its there on the main HTML page but heavily scrambled... hahaha I've been looking at this thing for quite some time now ... its *possible* you can get the data you want but it requires some work

Comment: I've actually managed to unscramble the table.. what the author has done is simply iterate along the string two chars at a time, swapping the characters. Its a bit of a pain as there's a few bits to unscramble but its a pretty nice challenge to unpick! Will update shortly with any luck

Comment: See latest edit - I'm sure you'll agree its not straight forward and I'm sure you can tweak it to work better than it does but its been a long hackathon getting that one working. That webmaster doesn't particularly like bots.

Comment: Yeah, I got that same impression about the bots. Got blocked for 48 hours for 150+ page views/datamining.
Nonetheless, thanks for the help!! Much appreciated.

Comment: pls upvote/accept answer if its good :D It was a pretty tough nut to crack and I spent a lot more time on this than I normally would (for internets-points)! lol